# Return True if exactly matches interger value to 1 or float value to 1.0

Tags: python

```
1 import random
2
3 def choice():
4     floatVal = round(random.uniform(0,1), 1)
5     return bool(floatVal)
6
7 print choice()
```

#1: line: 5 --> return True on exact 1.0 or return False on exact 0.0 else return nothing (None)

#2: I can handle easily by checking floatVal with if condition before type casting but I wish to return True when floatVal is really 1.0 (a kind of boolean with strict value).

Comment: "I can handle easily by checking floatVal with if condition" so why don't you? I don't exactly understand what you are asking.

Comment: If there’s a question here, I’m not seeing it. Do you’ve a problem with this code? What do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do

```
return True if floatVal == 1 else False if floatVal == 0 else None
```

Or you could try

```
return bool(a) if a == bool(a) else None
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5 adds the [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality) in PEP 485, to check equality of 2 number or close.

Relative tolerance is the maximum allowed difference between isclose arguments, relative to the larger absolute value:

```
>>> import math
>>> a = 5.0
>>> b = 4.99998
>>> math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-5)
True
>>> math.isclose(a, b, rel_tol=1e-6)
False
```

It is also possible to compare two values using absolute tolerance, which must be a non-negative value:

```
>>> import math
>>> a = 5.0
>>> b = 4.99998
>>> math.isclose(a, b, abs_tol=0.00003)
True
>>> math.isclose(a, b, abs_tol=0.00001)
False
```